# AsyncTask doesn't working with finding a file

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've written this code for training but it's always returning null (I checked the sdcard and file exists, and also checked required permissions).

```
private class FindRec extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, File>{
    ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(Albums.this, "Finding...", "");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... album) {
        File e1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/bluetooth/" + album + ".zip");
        if (e1.exists()) {
            return e1;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        if (result == null) {
          //I always get this toast.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Album Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            setfile(result);
        }

    }
```

then in my oncreate:

```
...
new FindRec().execute(albumname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive an array of strings in doInBackground, so fetch the first element of that array instead of implicitly converting the array to a string.

```
File e1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
        "/bluetooth/" + 
        album[0] + ".zip");
```